# Separating decades and centuries in python

Tags: python

I have a program I'm creating where I need to be able to take a year, as an integer, and separate the century from the decade:

```
year=1970
decade=70
century=1900
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
year= new Year(1970)
dec= year.decade
cent=year.century
```

I know I'll have to create a Year object and implement those two methods, but my issue is in the math, how do I take a year and extract just the decade and/or century?

I had tried passing it to a function as a string then building an integer out of the last two values in the string, but I ran into trouble with data types and want a 'native integer' way of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Stormy

Comment: I don't know what you're planning to do but note that 1900 and 1970 are not in the same century, 1970 and 2000 are though.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
decade = year - (year%10)
```

Comment: The answer is just fine.considering it is a fairly late answer, a detail on why your method works is a plus to have.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the year by 100 (integer only). The result is the century:

```
1972 / 100 = 19
```

(Of course, multiply again with 100 to get 1900).

The remainder is the year within that century:

```
1972 - (19 * 100) = 72
```

Do the same if you want to get the decade of the year with 10:

```
72 / 10 = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [divmod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=divmod#divmod) builtin function:

```
>>> divmod(1664, 100)
(16, 64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just convert your year in string, then take the two first char and add 00 and take the two ending char. That would look like that:

```
year = 1970
stringyear = str(1970)
century = stringyear[:2] + "00"
century = int(century)
print century
decade = stringyear[2:]
decade = int(decade)
print decade
```

There is probably a simpler way but it work well.

Comment: i really want to avoid casting  strings to integers.  I am creating a little program to calculate the chinese zodiac abnimal for a given year.  There are only 12 of them and  store them in an array, in order, I take the last two digits of the year  and get the modulus the year%12 and that returns the correct index of the array for the corresponding animal. iIf i don't  strip out the century, it doesn't give the correct answer,

Comment: The solution by Martin Nyolt is much better in your case (and any case whatsoever in fact).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, year%100 returns the decade quite nicely.

here is the finished version of my program that works...

```
critters=('Rat','ox', 'tiger','rabbit', 'dragon', 'snake', 'horse', 'ram', 'monkey', 'rooster', 'dog', 'pig')

def docrit(yrint):
    modval=yrint%12
    return critters[modval]

def wieder():
    go=input('Again[y,n]')
    if go=='y':
      return True
    else:
      return False

def main():
    print('Chinese Zodiac Calculator')
    yob=int(input('year: '))
    cent=int(yob/100)
    decade=yob%100
    print('century: ',cent)
    print('decade: ',decade)
    ani=docrit(decade)
    print('the animal is ',ani)
    if wieder()== True:
      main()
    else:
      exit()

def exit():
    print("I'm done. Bye.")
    return 0

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
import math

year = 1930

decade = math.floor((year-1)%100/10)*10
```

Decade will be 20's which is correct since 20's are from 1921 to 1930. Yeah is strange. But if you want 1930 to belong to the 30's, just strip the -1